# Georeferencing tools missing the Vector tool bar in qgis

Tags: qgis

I am working with Windows 8.1 on Intel Core i7 with QGIS.
When I open the Vector menu some options are missing like the "Georeferencing tools"

[image]

I choose all the vector and digitizing plugins I can find, but still a lot of options are missing from the Vector menu.

In a Dell PC this problem did not happen.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check if it is active in the plugins menue?

Comment: Please do not include thanks in your questions (or answers) - that is what votes are for - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950

Comment: Yes I have check, and all the plugin are active

Comment: Same QGIS Version on both platforms? Same installation procedure? In the past I got such weird behavior when mixing up standalone installers with OSGeo4W installers...

Comment: Mybe this is the problum, I will look intio it

Answer (score 6):

You should check the Raster menu, where the georeferencer tool resides:

[image]

Comment: There are georeferencing tools in the Vector menu. I did not ask about the "Georeferencer" in the Raster menu.